# Excel if statement Based off multiple critirea in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi and thank you in advance, I am trying to Select the cost from one table to another based off the fields: "client" and "Supply" each client has a different price for the supply some also have more supplies than others however in this example I have left it with 4 each as that shouldn't matter in the end.

Here is the cost table naming the client and supply name, (yes many of my clients have the same supply)

[image: Supply cost table]

The next image is of my End result table, where I am trying to get a If statment/lookup to find the person and supply of which it is and insert the cost associated with it

[image: end result table]

Currently I have Tried: `=IFS($A$2=Table2[@Client],"",[@Supply]=Table2[@Supply],Table2[@Cost])`

But unsure how to get it to look through the whole table, and a if vlookup that just did not work.

If anyone could help me out this would be great because I need something like this multiple times

Answer (score 2):

If you would fill down "Client" to create a proper-dataset, you can use `SUMIFS()`:

[image]

Formula in `H2`:

```
=SUMIFS(Table2[Cost],Table2[Client],[@Client],Table2[Supply],[@Supply])*[@Quantity]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "fill down" for a proper dataset?

Comment: @Ranjar, in it's current status your 2nd table is not considered proper tabular data where every column of a table represents a particular variable, and each row corresponds to a given record of the dataset in question. Note that filling down the clients name accordingly made life a lot easier.

Comment: oh right, but surely on the [@Client] I can just change to $A$2? since the way i presented it is the format I need to use, is that fine?  oh also how would i call a table from a different sheet?

Comment: Sure @Ranjar. Not a problem.

Comment: Sorry, that formula doesn't actually work for what im looking for, as If the client changes to "person 3" it no longer functions unless they are in the same row as the supply table

Comment: @Ranjar, I don't know what you mean by that. If I change the client name in my setup it works just fine.